# How to Pass values to a text box in telerik RadPageView

Tags: c#, telerik

Im trying to pass a value to a text box in the telerik RadPageView. when my event get fired code runs without any issues. but the value is not shown in the text box. Is this something to do with the RadPageView or am i missing something.

[image]

Code Behind..

```
  protected void btnAddInflow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        try
        {
            txtBankCode.Text = "TEST ONE";
        }
catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLog(ex.ToString()); commonUI.DisplayMessage(1, ex.Message);
        }
 }
```

Comment: Are you trying to show the value in the text box on page_load or a click of a button event?

Comment: Click Button Event